# In xamarin.ios bluetooth-central not act as it should

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have xamarin forms application which uses BLE peripheral device to update database. I do not want to interrupt this process when entering into background. For that purpose i included in info.plist on iOS project this:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>bluetooth-central</string>
</array>
```

which done nothing. I changed side 2 times in foreground, 5 times in background and 2 times in foreground again and i have that log:

```
3/16/2017 10:27:30 AM breadcrumb: Sucessfully started
3/16/2017 10:27:30 AM breadcrumb: Navigated to MainPage
3/16/2017 10:27:31 AM breadcrumb: Activated
3/16/2017 10:27:31 AM breadcrumb: StatisticsPage appeared
3/16/2017 10:27:50 AM breadcrumb: SideChanged
3/16/2017 10:28:42 AM breadcrumb: SideChanged
3/16/2017 10:28:45 AM breadcrumb: Enter background
3/16/2017 10:28:58 AM breadcrumb: EnterForeground
3/16/2017 10:28:59 AM breadcrumb: Activated
3/16/2017 10:29:04 AM breadcrumb: SideChanged
3/16/2017 10:29:08 AM breadcrumb: SideChanged
```

no side changes in background. What I forgot to do and where I should search?

**Edit1:**
I made a sample app on xamarin.iOS and everything works fine. Looks like there is something in my code. But i will appreciate any help with this.

**Edit2:**
I removed all code from my project until nothing left and it's still does not work!
[my broken app](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=48984575437956269397)
[sample working app](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=69839231791306286631)

Comment: Any update on this? I'm having the same issue: locking screen and waiting for 10 seconds results in iOS killing the app due to continuous BLE-events.

Comment: @Yenthe thats fine. you should not work in background continuously. Only awake on ble event, handle it and go to sleep again.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `bluetooth-peripheral` as your value in the info.plist entry.

Comment: I dont have any characteristics on phone side. Anyway tried this and it did not helped.